# Нужна ли запятая в данном длинном предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

> Естественное желание сохранить традиции предков, не потерять собственную идентичность в рамках всеобщей глобализации(,) и характерная для Востока черта идеализировать прошлое вкупе с активизацией различных религиозных движений, зачастую экстремистского характера, финансируемых Саудовской Аравией, странами Залива – все это приводит к мощному традиционалистскому движению,...

Нужна ли зпт в скобках? Не могу определить правило.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Зпт ни в скобках, ни без них не нужна: в предложение два однородных члена (подлежащие), соединённые одиночным союзом *и:*

желание (сохранить, не потерять) и черта (такая-сякая вкупе с тем-сем).